# Xamarin, is there a way to update list on picker when user changes it's mind?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.listview

without hitting Done. for example user selects 2 first, so list updates 1,3,4 are available on picker 2, but when i changes it to 1 then hit done 3 and 4 are the only ones available.  It's triggering to update list everytime even when DONE is not pressed yet on Picker.

I can't seem to find the right or come close to a solution

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace demo
{
// by visiting https://aka.ms/xamarinforms-previewer
[DesignTimeVisible(true)]
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
List<string> list;

public MainPage()
{
InitializeComponent();
list = new List<string>();

list.Add("1");
list.Add("2");
list.Add("3");
list.Add("4");
drainxy1();
drainxy2();
drainxy3();
drainxy4();


drainlocationPicker1.SelectedIndexChanged += 
drain1Handle_SelectedIndexChanged;
drainlocationPicker2.SelectedIndexChanged += 
drain2Handle_SelectedIndexChanged;         
drainlocationPicker3.SelectedIndexChanged += 
drain3Handle_SelectedIndexChanged;
drainlocationPicker4.SelectedIndexChanged += 
drain4Handle_SelectedIndexChanged;
}

private void drain4Handle_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

private void drain3Handle_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
drainlocationPicker1.IsEnabled = false;
drainlocationPicker2.IsEnabled = false;
drainlocationPicker4.Items.Remove((string)drainlocationPicker3.SelectedIte
m);

}

private void drain2Handle_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
drainlocationPicker1.IsEnabled = false;

drainlocationPicker3.Items.Remove((string)drainlocationPicker2.SelectedIte
m);            
drainlocationPicker4.Items.Remove((string)drainlocationPicker2.SelectedIte
m);

}

private void drain1Handle_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

drainlocationPicker2.Items.Remove((string)drainlocationPicker1.SelectedItem);            
drainlocationPicker3.Items.Remove((string)drainlocationPicker1.SelectedItem);           
drainlocationPicker4.Items.Remove((string)drainlocationPicker1.SelectedItem);
}

void drainxy1()
{
foreach (var item in list)
{
    drainlocationPicker1.Items.Add(item);
}
}
void drainxy2()
{

foreach (var item in list)
{
    drainlocationPicker2.Items.Add(item);
}
}
void drainxy3()
{

foreach (var item in list)
{
    drainlocationPicker3.Items.Add(item);
}
}
void drainxy4()
{

foreach (var item in list)
{
drainlocationPicker4.Items.Add(item);
}
}
}
}
```

Comment: It seems you have four pickers and one list view. What operations do you want to manipulate? I can't understand what you describe above: but when I change it to 1 then hit done 3 and 4 are the only ones available. What does one mean? Picker 1 or selecting 1. Could you specify it?

Comment: So I have 4 pickers with 1 list view 1,2,3,4. If user selects 2 on picker 1, picker 2 will have available list selection of list 1,3,4. But then if user changes its mind then selects 1 instead, the listview selection on picker 2 removes 1and2, now left with 3and4. The code works if the user doesn't change his user selection on every picker

Comment: So the problem is only IOS. it updates list without having to press done.

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behavior for pickers on iOS. If you want it to update only once "Done" is tapped you need to add this for every picker:

`pickerName.On<iOS>().SetUpdateMode(UpdateMode.WhenFinished);` where `pickerName` is the `x:Name="pickerName"` assigned to the picker in your xaml.

This can also be done in the xaml, but its a little messy and adds a permanent blue squiggle which annoys me.

Edit: See [Picker Item Selection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/ios/picker-selection) for doing it in xaml.

Now that picker will not change the value until done is pressed.

Comment: put in in IOS file, make a page for IOS?

Comment: you can place it right in your MainPage.cs file. if you're not using xaml, you just need to do `myPicker.On<iOS>().SetUpdateMode(UpdateMode.WhenFinished)`

Comment: is there another option for IOS picker to behave like android? it's frustrating.  I actually using Xaml, so do you have any clue on how to do this?

Comment: [Picker Item Selection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/ios/picker-selection) - This is the documentation. It has an example of how to set this in your xaml file so you don't need any extra code in your xaml.cs file.